# Run Objective C based on USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM

Tags: ios, uitableview, admob

I'm using the following code to display Admob banner in the `Header` of 
`tableView`. The banner should be display on iPhone only, but not iPad. This code work on iPhone, but my crashed on iPad. Where I went wrong?

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        GADBannerView *sampleView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];

        sampleView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-mycode";

        sampleView.rootViewController = self;

        [sampleView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

        return sampleView;
    }
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show ur crash report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return a UIView (or subclass, or nil) from the method. When on iPhone you're returning the sampleView, but you're not returning anything when this method is run on the iPad.

If you don't want to return a view when on iPad, then do the following:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        GADBannerView *sampleView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];

        sampleView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-mycode";

        sampleView.rootViewController = self;

        [sampleView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

        return sampleView;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why two `if` statements? Just use an `else` on the first `if`. There are only two idioms.

Comment: @rmaddy - you're absolutely correct - I was just trying to keep my modification of the OP's code example as minimal as possible, but yes, an else would have been better and I'll correct mine.

Answer (score 0):

Method's return type is `UIView` so you have to return `UIView` object. if there is no object means view to show then return `nil`.